# Creating a GKE node pool results in Error 429: Too many operations: cluster "testcluster" hits the concurrent operations quota 1

Tags: kubernetes

While creating a nodepool with terraform, we are seeing the following error

```
2023-06-29 15:49:25,017 - Error: error creating NodePool: googleapi: Error 429: Too many operations: cluster "testcluster" hits the concurrent operations quota 1, please try again later.
```

2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 - Details:
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 - [
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 -   {
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 -     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 -     "requestId": "0xd57aa0cb25cb8889"
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 -   }
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 - ]
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 - , rateLimitExceeded
2023-06-29 15:49:25,018 -

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, I am deploying a GKE cluster with 3 node pools in europe-west9 region.
2 of them are well deployed but with the third one I get the following error :

│ Error: error creating NodePool: googleapi: Error 429: Too many operations: cluster "gke-cluster" hits the concurrent operations quota 1, please try again later.

│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
│     "requestId": "0xd6d5bb211b74b0a9"
│   }
│ ]
│ , rateLimitExceeded
│
│   with module.gke["myproject"].google_container_node_pool.primary_nodes["node-pool-3"],
│   on modules/gke/main.tf line 86, in resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_nodes":
│   86: resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_nodes" {